# error on a webpack project: this._handle.spawn

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a webpack project and when I run `npm run start` I always got below error. This project used to work fine and this error happens when I setup a new development machine.

```
Installing babel-preset-es2015...
Installing babel-preset-react...
npm WARN go2nurse@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN go2nurse@1.0.0 No repository field.
Executing pre-build scripts
internal/child_process.js:289
  var err = this._handle.spawn(options);
                         ^

TypeError: Bad argument
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:289:26)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:385:9)
    at handleScript (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack-shell-plugin/lib/index.js:180:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack-shell-plugin/lib/index.js:224:38)
    at Compiler.applyPlugins (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:26:37)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:364:7)
    at Compiler.compile (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:392:25)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:173:9)
    at Compiler.readRecords (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:302:10)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:170:8)
    at Compiler.next (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:67:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js:23:3)
    at Compiler.next (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:69:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:22:58)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:71:13)
    at Compiler.run (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:167:7)
    at processOptions (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:188:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joey/dev/cooltoo/go2nurse_android/app/src/main/webres/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:192:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Below is my node, webpack, npm version.

```
$ npm -v
3.10.9
$ node -v
v7.2.0
$ webpack -v
webpack 1.13.3
```

My webpack-dev-server version is: `webpack-dev-server 1.16.2`

Is there any version mis-match problem?